# How to create a detect app is foreground hooks in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I wrote a hooks to detect app is foreground with `RN 0.69.4` like this:

```
export const useIsForeground = (): boolean => {
  const [isForeground, setIsForeground] = useState(AppState.currentState === 'active');

  useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = (state: AppStateStatus): void => {
      setIsForeground(state === 'active');
    };
    const listener = AppState.addEventListener('change', onChange);
    return () => listener?.remove();
  }, [setIsForeground]);

  return isForeground;
};
```

And I use it in another FC:

```
export default function () {
  const isAppForeground = useIsForeground(); // warning stack on this line
  return isAppForeground ? <ComponentA /> : <ComponentB />;
}
```

But when I go in this page, I got this warning:

```
`new NativeEventEmitter()` was called with a non-null argument without the required `removeListeners` method.
```

I this I had remove the listener correctly, but this warning make me puzzled. So where I make the mistake? And how can I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function useIsAppForeground () {
    const [isForeground, setForeGround] = useState(true)

    console.log("isForeground: " + isForeground)
    useEffect(() => {
        const list = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => {
            console.log("nextAppState: " + nextAppState)
            setForeGround(nextAppState === 'active')
        })

        return () => {
            list.remove()
        }
    }, [])

    return isForeground
}
```